# Why we sometimes subcribe to observable sometimes not?

Tags: angular

*I am new at Angular. if I am wrong tell me please.
I know that if we want to watch observable if someting is change or not, we should subscribe it. But some videos I watch to learn, sometimes we subscribe sometimes not. for example;*

```
export class AppComponent {
   signedin$: boolean = false;


  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.signedin$ = this.authService.signedin$;  //this.authService.signedin$ is BehaviorSubject
  }



      ngOnInit() {
          // We subscribe here to watch.
         this.authService.signedin$.subscribe((signedin) => {
          this.signedin = signedin;
         });
       }

}
```

However,

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad {


  constructor(private service: AuthService) {

  }

  canLoad(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[]
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

   // we dont subscribe here?

   return this.service.signedin$.pipe(
      skipWhile((value) => value === null),
      take(1)
    );
  }
}
```

*I confused that why we are not subcribing here  ? what is difference ?*

Comment: because it will be subscribed to somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

A route guard in Angular can return a `boolean`, a `Promise` of type `boolean` or an `Observable` of type `boolean`. In your case, you are returning an `Observable<boolean>` so Angular waits until it is resolved to either `true` or `false` to determine if it is allowed to route there or not.

https://alligator.io/angular/route-guards/